# Resources should be closed - Sonar

Tags: java, optimization, sonarqube, inputstream, findbugs

I have the following piece of code:

```
public static byte[] readSomeFile(String filePath) {
 byte[] buffer = new byte[FILE_SIZE];
 FileInputStream fileIn = null;
 BufferedInputStream buffIn = null;
 DataInputStream inData = null;

 int size = 0;
 byte[] someArray= null;
 try {
  fileIn = new FileInputStream(filePath);
  buffIn = new BufferedInputStream(fileIn);
  inData = new DataInputStream(buffIn);
  size = inData.read(buffer, 0, FILE_SIZE);
  someArray= new byte[size];
  System.arraycopy(buffer, 0, someArray, 0, size);
 } catch (IOException e) {
  //log(Log.ERROR,"IO ERROR: " + e.toString());
 } finally {
  try {
   if (null != fileIn) {
    fileIn.close();
   }
   if (null != buffIn) {
    buffIn.close();
   }
   if (null != inData) {
    inData.close();
   }
  } catch (Exception exFinally) {
   // some stuff
   someArray= null;
  }
 }
 return someArray;
}
```

the problem is Sonar is still complaining about `fileIn` not being closed, although it's the first resource addressed in the finally block.

How does Sonar work in this case ? and how to resolve the ***Resources should be closed*** rule ?

Comment: I don't know if it'll fix the Sonar issue but you don't need to `try-catch` in your `finally` clause - just checking if the `InputStream` objects is null and closing them if not is enough, according to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html

Comment: Please add exFinally.printStackTrace() in the the catch block to see if there is any exception occurs during closing the resource

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have to use the `Java 7` and above, I prefer you to use `try with resources` which was introduced in `Java 7` new features.

`Try-with-resources` in `Java 7` is a new `exception` handling mechanism that makes it easier to correctly close resources that are used within a `try-catch block.`

As to your code:

```
finally {
  try {
   if (null != fileIn) {
    fileIn.close();
   }
   if (null != buffIn) {
    buffIn.close();
   }
   if (null != inData) {
    inData.close();
   }
  } catch (Exception exFinally) {
   // some stuff
   someArray= null;
  }
 }
```

**Do you notice that ugly double try?**

But, if you used the `try with resources` , `close()` is automatically called, if it `throws` an `Exception` or not, it will be supressed [(as specified in the Java Language Specification 14.20.3)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.3) . Same happens for your case. I hope it helps.

So, your code will be looked like:

```
public static byte[] readSomeFile(String filePath) {
         byte[] buffer = new byte[FILE_SIZE];
         int size = 0;
         byte[] someArray= null;
         try (FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(filePath);
                 BufferedInputStream buffIn = new BufferedInputStream(fileIn);
                 DataInputStream inData = new DataInputStream(buffIn);) {

          size = inData.read(buffer, 0, FILE_SIZE);
          someArray= new byte[size];
          System.arraycopy(buffer, 0, someArray, 0, size);
         } catch (IOException e) {
          //log(Log.ERROR,"IO ERROR: " + e.toString());
         } 
         return someArray;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but the problem here, is that I want to return null if there is a problem with the .close() method, which a cannot do with the try-with-resources mechanism.

Comment: you can just return someArray which initialized in your method. it's not need to check close or not. Your programmitacally open resources must close if any errors occred in method. Think about it.

Comment: OK, sounds great, let me try it first :)

Comment: Ofcourse, also note that it's also best design in  Java. I'm sure Sonar and Findbugs will never complain about this code.